# Can only get swipe code working on desktop, not mobile

Tags: jquery, touch

I've tried and failed miserably to get touch working on mobile. I found Ben Major's jquery touch event library (can't post link as I'm new) which is great - so much easier to use than jquery mobile or hammer (I am a beginner and I could not make those work properly). However... I've got a gallery working on desktop but I just cannot figure out why, when I push it to my GitHub pages, it will not work on mobile devices (have tried Chrome and Safari on iPhone 6s and iPad Pro). Can anyone help? It's so frustrating! It can't be that hard even for a beginner but I've googled everything under the sun and still no luck.

Ps ideally I'd add the touch events to the dynamically created elements of $slide, $prev and $next but that doesn't even work on desktop. The prev and next buttons on top of the slides also don't work except on desktop - I was hoping that this was a touch issue and I just needed to add "tap" but can't.

Maybe I've missed something really obvious?!?

Here’s the repository: https://github.com/charlottejunker/charlottejunker.github.io/tree/master/mike_ragan_portfolio
Here’s it hosted: http://charlottejunker.github.io/mike_ragan_portfolio/portfolio.html

THANK YOU!

Comment: you have `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`  error in your site:- http://charlottejunker.github.io/mike_ragan_portfolio/portfolio.html   on gallery.js :14 line  which is:- `$('.project').mousedown(function() {
   $(this).parents().css(
     'background-color', '#fff',
   );` you need to change last `);` to `});`   and then check

Comment: Thanks but that's throwing up an error for me - the function is closed on line 18 after the second css declaration... am I missing something?

Comment: you need to remove all jQuery errors shown in your browser console. When all errors resolve then only something will work

Comment: Yeah I'm getting zero errors in the console which is why I'm so confused. Bizarre!!